# PyQGIS: Multiply fields and populate new field

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to populate field "L_M" with the default value of "Length" or with the result of multiplication between "Length" and 0.3048 if "LengthUnit" = 2, which stands for Feets.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

# create layer
layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer() 
it = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest())


layer.startEditing()

# add field

new_Field1 = "L_M"
idq = layer.fieldNameIndex(new_Field1)

if idq == -1:
    layer.addAttribute(QgsField(new_Field1, QVariant.Double, 'double', 20, 4))

layer.updateFields() # tell the vector layer to fetch changes from the provider

idl = layer.fieldNameIndex('Length')
e = QgsExpression ("idl * 0.3048")
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

for feat in it:
    if feat['LengthUnit'] == 2:
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), layer.fieldNameIndex('L_M'), e.evaluate(feat))
    else:
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), layer.fieldNameIndex('L_M'), idl)

layer.updateFields() # tell the vector layer to fetch changes from the provider
```

The result I get is 'L_M' field populated with '10.000' value, and *NULL* value for entries with 'LengthUnit' = 2.

What is the best approach to get the multiplication between fields in a new field?

P.S. As I see it, my script doesn't even read proper values from the 'Length' field, which I don't know why. It's a Double type field also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QGSExpression considers the column name, not the column ID. So you would need to change your expression to

```
e = QgsExpression ('"Length"* 0.3048')
```

Then in the loop, the `else` case should set the value of the feature's length, not of the field ID

```
    else:
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), layer.fieldNameIndex('L_M'), feat['Length'])
```

Comment: Perfect @JGH. Many thanks for pointing that out. Another thing was to make the field name escape: e = QgsExpression ("\"Length\" * 0.3048")

Comment: @kidd ah yes, I have updated the answer